# Kernel of the transpose of the differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be the functional

$$
\int_{0}^{1} p(x)dx
$$
defined on the space $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of polynomials with real coefficients. Let $D$ the differential operator. Compute $ker D^T(F)$ and $ker (D^T)^k(F)$.

I have no clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start by computing $D^T F$. We have for any $p \in \def\Pol{\mathbf R[X]}\Pol$, that
\begin{align*}
  (D^T F)(p) &= F(Dp)\\
             &= \int_0^1 Dp(x)\, dx\\
             &= p(1) - p(0)
\end{align*}
That is $D^T F$ is the functional, that maps $p$ to $p(1) - p(0)$, hence 
$$ \ker (D^T F) = \{ p\in \Pol \mid p(1) = p(0) \} $$
As $(D^T)^k = (D^k)^T$, we have 
$$ (D^T)^k F(p) = F(D^k p) = D^{k-1}p(1) - D^{k-1}p(0) $$
and hence 
$$ \ker (D^T)^k F = \{ p \in \Pol \mid D^{k-1}p(1) = D^{k-1}p(0)\} $$